# Structuring of .py project using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've written a 'simple' python project in my spare time to get myself familiar with the language, but now I want to take it up a level. This includes storing data to a database for persistance. However, I'm having a hard-time to figure out the structuring of my project. My first attempt locked me out through circular dependencies.

I have a _dbhandler.py;

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import os

engine = create_engine(os.getenv('DB'), echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

and according to the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), this is how I want to structure my python object if I want to store it's data to a db;

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, Unicode
from _dbhandler import Base, Session


class ServerSettings(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ServerSettings'
    guildID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    channelID = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, guild_id):
        self.guild_id = guild_id
        self.channel_id = None
```

now my initial attempt was to put any modification of the serversettings-object through a 'save-method' in the dbhandler;

```
# store a changed channel id to the db
async def save_channel(guild_id, channel_id):
    with Session() as session:
        settings_obj = (session.query(ServerSettings).filter_by(guildID=guild_id).first())
        settings_obj.channel_id = channel_id
        session.commit()
```

however, to be able to compile, I'll need to add `from _serversettings import ServerSettings`. When I do so, I get circular dependencies, and lock myself out. I've tried to move it to the ServerSettings SetChannel-method, but it just feels out of place there. Putting it there'd force me to move any 'GetServerSettings'-method to edit the object in the main.py - and I've 'learned' this should be as empty as possible in a clean project. On top of that, the method gets kind of bloated - looking for a db-record to reference itself to ..;

```
def set_channel(self, channel):
    if channel is not None:
        self.channel_id = channel.id
    else:
        self.channel_id = None

    with Session() as session:
        settings_obj = (session.query(ServerSettings).filter_by(guildID=self.guild_id).first())
        settings_obj.channel_id = self.channel_id
        session.commit()
```

I feel like I'm way out of my depth, but I'm also having a hard time determining what is the 'best practice', or how to read up on it. The examples and tutorials I've found so far show mostly snippets, but I'm looking for general purpose project-structuring. Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me the most intuitive structure for sqlalchemy is having a db module that creates the engine, base and sessions. I create modules per functionality group, mainly for naming, with classes (tables) which often also provide save() functions for 'fire and forget' mutations. These modules form a component that have their own logs, error handling, startup and maintenance.

So within my project that is the first clear separation of sqlalchemy stuff. Then there's a group of modules with functions that implement business logic, but heavily rely on sqlalchemy. Complex queries, transactions and datamutations happen in this component. These functions can be seen as workers and helpers.

The ui, http, scheduler and main components therefore are almost never waiting for sqlalchemy/the database. This is in no way enforced, but in situations like yours 'it doesn't feel right to be doing this in main' it helps deciding what to do where. In general it supports your workflow, especially when debugging, refactoring and writing logs. But don't put to much effort in planning for structure; there's no perfect way and stuff always changes down the line.

Comment: I come from a different language as I'm trying to teach myself python, so if I get what you're saying;
     - the class-object (instancing) is treated like an interface
     - objects are retrieved from the db 'in-line' during operations with the dbhandler's 'session', i.e. they happen not ín the dbhandler, but in whatever module needs the db-object
      - objectmodification is done through a different, yet still class-specific module that import both the 'interface' and the dbhandler to prevent circular dependencies.
Unless I missunderstood you somewhere along the lines ?

Comment: Actually - can you provide a code-snippet of how you incorporate that `save()`-function you talk about in your first paragraph? Because now that I've read your answer a couple times over, I think I'm pretty far along your line of thought. Maybe my issue is more in how to execute what I want to do, rather than what I want to do in the first place.